# Codeigniter V 3.0 flashdata issue

Tags: codeigniter, session

In codeigniter v3.0 when printing message like

**$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'XAdded Successfully');**

here added successfully written inside a div tag with some classes of bootstrap to assign error div 
then all the session data is destroyed automatically  and when writing the same code as

**$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Added Successfully');**

then it is working fine when it is written a simple text

is anyone facing the same problem problem please help me suggesting the issue to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter flash data only works on redirect

Place redirect and session where need must have redirect though.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success: You have added a new banner!');

redirect('admin/design/banners');
```

And on view could where you redirect to

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('error')) { ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error');?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success')) { ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="alert alert-info">
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious reply . i m redirecting it to my view but problem is that i am seting flashadata as $this->session->set_flashdata('success', '<div class="alert alert-success fade in block-inner"><button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">X</button><i class="icon-cancel-circle"></i>>Success: You have added a new banner!</div>'); like this then it destroy the entire session but if set simple success message like yours it works fine...it works fine in codeigniter v2.0 but when i updrade it to v3.0 it starts problem

Comment: I remember Jim one of the owners of codeigniter saying that the sessions on codeigniter 3 are not quite full tested yet so you may come across problem. Probably best to stick to CI 2 until CI 3 has a beta version still in development I think.

Comment: yeah you are right , but client has asked to upgrade it to v3.0 so we have to find a solution for it....but your code can work properly by placing div on view rather than in flash message